# how to use context in drivers with a function in python?

Tags: python, drivers

How do i use "context" in a driver function correctly? i know i shouldn't use "bpy.context".

This is my function:

```
 import bpy


    def getLeftVal():
    
    
        depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

        return 69
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think drivers are supposed to work with animation and animation is supposed to be rendered, but rendering does not always have regular context for example when rendering from command line, so the way I see it, it might be that one just isn't supposed to use context in drivers at all. I would use handlers. They might suffer the same issues in some situations, but I think they would be more reliable than drivers if it's even possible to do with drivers.

Comment: good idea! thank you!